# VSCode Pyramid Debug

Tags: python, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, pyramid

I am struggling to configure [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on a Linux machine to start debugging a pyramid app (via pserve) without any success.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? What did you observe? What errors are reported?

Comment: Same here, could not find a single extension or a workaround.

Comment: Found https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/519, but this leads to ValueError: source code can not control null byte.

Comment: I've the same issue when trying to create a `lauch.json` file I got this error `E+00000.007: Error determining module path for sys.argv`

Answer (score 1):

I was successful to debug my Pyramid application using the `program` option under Linux using this VS code `launch.json` file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Pyramid Application",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "FullPathToExecutableFileHere",
      "args": [
        "param1",
        "${workspaceFolder}/XXX.ini"
      ],
      "pyramid": true,
      "jinja": true
    }
  ]
}
```

By giving the full path to the executable file, and providing the parameters in the `args` section.

I can now set a break point in any python source file code.

**Don't forget to set the path of the python interpreter to the specific python virtual environment** needed by your application using `CTRL` + `Shift` + `P`

Comment: worked like a charm ! "FullPathToExecutableFileHere" being path to pserve command, for more clarity